# Merge two Artifactories into one

Tags: artifactory

I've two old Artifactories and I want to merge into a modern one.

I exported and imported one into new one, but, what's the procedure for second one? If I import the exported content, it overwrites all previous in the new one?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you tried full system export / import - this is indeed not the way to achieve your goal, it is more a backup and restore.
Instead you should do a repository level export & import - export your repositories from the source Artifactory and then import them into the target Artifactory.
For more details, refer to the [Importing and Exporting - Repository Level](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-RepositoriesImportandExport) wiki page.